# Closing a Scala swing frame

Tags: scala, action, scala-swing

I am having a problem closing my Scala swing frame.  Here is the code for my exit button

```
val buttonExit = new Button {
  text = "Exit"
  action = Action("Exit") {
    WorldActor.run(false)
    closer
  }
}
```

The closer function is defined as:

```
def closer (){
  top.close
}
```

where top is the MainFrame.  Everytime I try to close, it just suspends and stops responding.

Comment: Is `WorldActor` a scala `Actor`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you can call

```
dispose()
```

on the Frame.

`dispose` is implemented on `scala.swing.Window` so applies to Frames and Dialogs.

Calling `dispose` closes (in a recoverable way, using `pack` and `visible = true` to re-open) additional Frames and terminates the application, if called on the last Frame.

To terminate the app on any Frame call `quit()` which calls any shutdown code provided before calling System.exit.

Here's a quick hack to illustrate

```
import swing._

object SwingThing extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {frame =>
    val sf = new Frame {secondFrame =>
      title   = "Secondary Frame"
      visible = true
      contents = new FlowPanel {
        contents += new Button(Action("Close Me") {secondFrame.dispose()})
        contents += new Button(Action("Exit")     {quit()})
      }
    }
    val recoverBtn = new Button(Action("Recover")  {sf.pack(); sf.visible = true})
    val closeBtn   = new Button(Action("Close Me") {frame.dispose()})
    val exitBtn    = new Button(Action("Exit")     {quit()})

    contents = new FlowPanel {
      contents += recoverBtn
      contents += closeBtn
      contents += exitBtn
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on Scala, but I have done some Java swing development. Try using

I think

```
WorldActor.run(false)
```

pauses the program, try removing that, also try adding `System.exit(0)`.

```
def closer(){
    exit(0) //Java's System.exit(0) ?
}
```

or maybe put `System.exit(0)` after `top.close`.

Also, have you set the default close operation to do nothing?

```
peer.setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)
```

Comment: Where and how do I set the default close operation in clasa.  Do you know?

Comment: You do it in the JFrame (MainFrame?) . Just type `setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` in the constructor code. Make sure you have imported `JFrame._;`. See [this](http://compsci.ca/v3/viewtopic.php?t=10491) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not skilled at `scala.swing._` but I think the following:

> where top is the MainFrame
>   How to define the MainFrame?

If you define as:

```
def top = new MainFrame { ... }
```

And the following code:

```
val a = top
val b = top
```

produces the two different instance.

So `b.close` does not close `a`.
And vice versa i.e. `a.close` does not close `b`.