# Why doesn't scala swing app exit when main frame is closed?

Tags: swing, scala

In the following minimal Scala Swing app, if I choose File->Exit (which calls `sys.exit`), or File->Quit (which calls `SimpleSwingApplication.quit`) then the application exits. If I choose File->Close (which calls `Frame.close`) then the window closes but the application doesn't exit (e.g. when run using `java -jar myexample.jar` it doesn't return to the prompt -- I have to ^C to kill it).

```
import scala.swing._
import swing.event.{Key,WindowClosed,WindowClosing}

object GUI extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  def top = new Frame {
    import javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE
    peer.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE)

    menuBar = new MenuBar {
      contents += new Menu("File") {
        mnemonic = Key.F
        contents += new MenuItem(Action("Exit") { sys.exit(0) }) { mnemonic = Key.X }
        contents += new MenuItem(Action("Close") { close() }) { mnemonic = Key.C }
        contents += new MenuItem(Action("Quit") { quit }) { mnemonic = Key.Q }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried a few different things, all with the same behavior:

- use `MainFrame` instead of `Frame`
- add a handler to `reactions` that matches `WindowClosing` and call `sys.exit` from there

  - added a reaction to both a `Frame` subclass (not shown here) and
  - to the `SimpleSwingApplication`
- `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` seemed like it should do the job, but whether it's there or not doesn't matter
- set default close operation to `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`
- override `Frame.closeOperation` to call `sys.exit`, but this doesn't seem to get called at all (I added a print there and it doesn't result in any output)

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8527715/67022), if I change the File->Close handler to call `dispose` instead of `close`, the app exits. The [docs for MainFrame say](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.swing.MainFrame):

> Shuts down the framework and quits the application when closed.

Which made me think that `close` should work.

**Why do I have to call `dispose` instead of `close` here?** Why doesn't `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` or overriding the `closeOperation` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you're calling on `swing.Window` is:

```
def close() { peer setVisible false }
```

which obviously isn't what you might assume.

Comment: Well, that answer is too terse for me. Could you please elaborate for the slow ones like me? Thx

Comment: @MartinQuinson i.e., `close` method is not what the doc on `MainFrame` means. Use `quit` and maybe in your `shutdown` call `frame.dispose`. I played with scala-swing when first learning scala, but I don't use it.

Comment: I'll upvote this as the most annoying downvote of 2020.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `GUI.quit()`.